# Tap outside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a series of `UICollectionViewCell`s in a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Each cell contains an `UIImageView` that, depending on the indexPath is bigger than the cell itself. The cell doesn't clip its content, so you can always see the whole image.

But I can't make the touches outside the cell's frame, but inside the image, to act as normal touches and fire the selection of the cell.

I tried overriding the methods `hitTest:withEvent` and `pointInside:withEvent` of the `UICollectionViewCell` but it makes no change.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.frame, point)) {
        NSLog(@"Contains: %d", cellIndex);
        return self;
    }
    NSLog(@"Doesn't contain: %d", cellIndex);

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}


- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.frame, point)) {
        NSLog(@"Inside: %d", cellIndex);
        return YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"Outside: %d", cellIndex);
    return NO;
}
```

When I have the first 3 elements of the collection view on screen and I go and tap on the third one (outside it's cell's frame, but inside the UIImageView) this is what it traces:

```
2013-05-06 10:53:38.395 Contigo[3351:c07] Doesn't contain: 0
2013-05-06 10:53:38.395 Contigo[3351:c07] Outside: 0
2013-05-06 10:53:38.396 Contigo[3351:c07] Contains: 2
2013-05-06 10:53:38.396 Contigo[3351:c07] Doesn't contain: 0
2013-05-06 10:53:38.396 Contigo[3351:c07] Outside: 0
2013-05-06 10:53:38.396 Contigo[3351:c07] Contains: 2
2013-05-06 10:53:38.396 Contigo[3351:c07] Doesn't contain: 0
2013-05-06 10:53:38.396 Contigo[3351:c07] Outside: 0
2013-05-06 10:53:38.397 Contigo[3351:c07] Contains: 2
```

Comment: What is userIntactionEnabled state of the ImageView?

Comment: It's set to YES, and hitTest:withEvent is doing the right thing returning self. But pointInside:withEvent, on the other hand, always returns NO (or is not getting called at all) even if I tap inside the cell.